# Create callback method from another Event Handler in C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

We can easily make a callback method in Unity like this:

```
private void SimpleCallbak(Action<bool> onTaskReady ) {

        // do something...
        onTaskReady(true);
    }
```

How do fire the callback **onAdReady** when **HandleInterstitialLoaded** event handler fire:

```
private void RequestInterstitialWithCallbak(Action<bool> onAdReady ) {

        interstitial = new InterstitialAd("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        interstitial.OnAdLoaded += HandleInterstitialLoaded;
        interstitial.LoadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().Build());

        onAdReady(true); //???????????
    }

    public void HandleInterstitialLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        Debug.Log("HandleInterstitialLoaded event received.");
        onAdReady(true); //???????????
    }
```

Comment: Store the `Action<bool>` in a member variable? Or you could replace `HandleInterstitialLoaded` with a lambda that captures the `Action<bool>`

Comment: Can you rephrase the question to be more clear what your ultimate goal is? It is not clear what you try to archive and why it is not possible with eg. member variables

Comment: @UnholySheep Could you please write an answer with your ideas? I am not that expert to use lambda!

Comment: @X39 I want to fire the callback onAdReady when ad is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple modification of your code, replacing the callback method with a lambda:

```
private void RequestInterstitialWithCallbak(Action<bool> onAdReady ) {
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    interstitial.OnAdLoaded += (sender, args) => {
        Debug.Log("HandleInterstitialLoaded event received.");
        onAdReady(true);
    };
    interstitial.LoadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().Build());
}
```

Here `sender` and `args` use type inference, allowing us to shorten the code a little bit by omitting the type specifiers

For more information on using lambdas for callbacks you can read the official documentation on [Delegates and lambdas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/delegates-lambdas) and [Lambda Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)

Answer (score 1):

I guess u r in rush to get an answer, this is based on UnholySheep' comment:

```
private Action<bool> _onAdReady;

private void RequestInterstitialWithCallbak(Action<bool> onAdReady)
{
    _onAdReady = onAdReady;
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    interstitial.OnAdLoaded += HandleInterstitialLoaded;
    interstitial.LoadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().Build());

    _onAdReady?.Invoke(true); //???????????
}

public void HandleInterstitialLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Debug.Log("HandleInterstitialLoaded event received.");
    _onAdReady?.Invoke(true); //???????????
}
```